# Using SearchView in Toolbar (not set as support ActionBar)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

in my app I have a fragment that own a Toolbar (support library).

I need to put a SearchView in that tollbar so I created a menu xml like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify_white_24dp"
      android:title="aaa"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

The following is the fragment code:

```
var toolbar = rootView.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.SetTitle (Resource.String.app_name);
toolbar.InflateMenu (Resource.Menu.Messages_list);
toolbar.MenuItemClick += Toolbar_MenuItemClick;

var item = toolbar.Menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.search).ActionView as Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView;
```

The problem is that *item* is null. This is very strange also beacuse the debugger tells my that it's really a SearchView.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `JavaCast<SearchView>()` instead of casting with `as`.

Comment: Thanks you! This did the trick!
Put your comment in an answer and I will mark it as the best one.
Just a curiosity: why should I use Android.Runtime.Javacast and not Java.Interop.Javacast?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there was a slight hint of the solution in @Martijn00's answer, but let me clarify.

Since you are using `SearchView` which comes from an external library, namely Support.v7, you need to use `JavaCast<T>()` in order to cast it correctly. `JavaCast<T>()` is needed when you need to perform Java-side object casts. There is a [nice explanation here by Jon Pryor](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7459#c3) on Xamarin's bugzilla why this is necessary.

Anyways you code should end up looking something like this:

```
var item = toolbar.Menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.search);
var searchView = item.ActionView.JavaCast<SearchView>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.search, menu);

        var searchMenu = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);

        var searchView = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(searchMenu).JavaCast<SearchView>();
    }
```

Comment: I think I cannot use your solution. The toolbar is not set as ActionBar. It's just a "normal" view